# SASS - How can I assign two classes the same style except one property?

Tags: css, sass, styles

I have a SASS stylesheet and I want to assign the same styles for two classes (.class and .otherclass) except for one property (before:) which should have another value for .otherclass.

This is the code I currently have:

```
.class, .otherclass {

    p { font-family:arial;
         &before: 
              @extend .class-one {}
    }

    ~ .extraclass {}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't except to reset that property. If you want to exclude a property from an extend, don't include it in the original definition.

Comment: Also your existing code does not reflect your description of the required result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be quite honest I'm not sure why u don't want to write two different selectors, or just overide some property in second one. E.g

```css
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
  
  &:before{
    content: 'class';
  }
}

.class2:before {
  content: 'class2';
}
```

Maybe using :not selector would be helpfull:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

```css
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
  &:before {
    content: 'class'
  }
  &:not(.class1):before{
    content: 'class23'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I though overriding was ideal with CSS but as I know little SASS I'd though I should ask.

Comment: Sass, Less and Stylus are just preprocessors of CSS. There is no reason to drop CSS properties when using SCSS. Pure CSS code is valid SCSS code :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to look like:

```
.test{
  $color:#f00;
}
.demo{
  &:extend(.test);
}
```